# Do until loop in vba

Tags: vba

I written a vba where when i roll 6000 times dice, it will count the number of 1's rolled 2's rolled and so on until number of 6's

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
i = 6000
Do Until i < 0
    n = Int(1 + Rnd * (6 - 1 + 1))
    TextBox1.Text = Range("A1")
    TextBox2.Text = Range("A2")
    TextBox3.Text = Range("A3")
    TextBox4.Text = Range("A4")
    TextBox5.Text = Range("A5")
    TextBox6.Text = Range("A6")

    If n = 1 Then
        Range("A1") = Range("A1") + n
    ElseIf n = 2 Then
        Range("A2") = Range("A2") + n / 2
    ElseIf n = 3 Then
        Range("A3") = Range("A3") + n / 3
    ElseIf n = 4 Then
        Range("A4") = Range("A4") + n / 4
    ElseIf n = 5 Then
        Range("A5") = Range("A5") + n / 5
    ElseIf n = 6 Then
        Range("A6") = Range("A6") + n / 6
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

It works fine but the problem is it loads so slow, is there a way to fasten this code ?

Comment: Definitely! Extract the values from the cells before the loop and store them in variables. Keep changing the values of the variables and only set the cells' values _after_ the loop is done its job.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim results As Variant

    results = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    ' read results from cells A1 - A6
    For i = 1 To 6
        results(i - 1) = Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i

    ' roll the dice 6000 times
    For i = 1 To 6000
        n = Int(Rnd * 6)
        results(n) = results(n) + 1
    Next i

    ' write results to cells A1 - A6
    For i = 1 To 6
        Cells(1, i).Value = results(i - 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It will give the result instantly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Arr(1 To 6) As Integer
    Dim n           As Integer                  ' random number: 1 to 6
    Dim i           As Long                     ' loop counter: turns
    
    Randomize
    For i = 1 To 6000
        n = Int(1 + Rnd * (6 - 1 + 1))
        Arr(n) = Arr(n) + 1
    Next i
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The interaction between text boxes and worksheet cells isn't clear. It's easy to establish in any way you want.

Comment: This works, but when i click again the button. the numbers counted resets.

Comment: That is because your question doesn't specify which numbers, if any, you want to preserve. There is also no mention of any flow or evaluation. Perhaps you want new results added to the worksheet or added to the text boxes or displayed in the next column. You just don't say. The best way would be to edit your question to include what you want.